# Move all lines between header and footer into new file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have file records like below, header, data & footer records.

I need to move only data part to another file.  New file should only contain lines between Header2 and Footer1.

I have tried t `head -n 30 fiename | tail 10 > newfile`
as data record counts may vary .

**example records from source file .**

```
Header1
Header2
Header3
SEQ++1
line1
line2
SEQ++2
line1
SEQ++3
line1
line2
line3
Footer1
Footer2
Footer3
```

Output file should have:

```
SEQ++1
line1
line2
SEQ++2
line1
SEQ++3
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: You will need to tell us how to differentiate headers/footers from regular lines.

Comment: Are head and foot limited by *tag string* (empty line) or by number or lines?

Comment: Lines between 'Header1' and 'Footer1' needs to be pulled out from file and save it to another file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways.

`grep`:

```
grep -v -E "Header|Footer" source.txt
```

`awk`:

```
awk '! /Header.|Footer./ { print }' source.txt
```

You can replace the "Header" and "Footer" values by whatever you use to identify each lines.